# Unless block never executed

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3 and my unless block is never executed

```
<th:block th:if="${products.productTypes gt 8 and products.productTypes lt 12}">
    <div th:replace="fragments/products/sub-granulates"/>
</th>
<th:unless="${products.productTypes gt 8 and products.productTypes lt 12}">
    <div th:replace="fragments/products/sub-traditional-products"/>
</th>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: can you add a tag <span th:text="${products.productTypes}"></span> to see the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

your th:bloc is not closed and for the unless, there is not th:block

Answer (score 1):

Your thymeleaf is malformed... it should look like this:

```
<th:block th:if="${products.productTypes gt 8 and products.productTypes lt 12}">
    <div th:replace="fragments/products/sub-granulates"/>
</th:block>

<th:block th:unless="${products.productTypes gt 8 and products.productTypes lt 12}">
    <div th:replace="fragments/products/sub-traditional-products"/>
</th:block>
```

I believe since thymeleaf 3, you could also simplify your code to look like this:

```
<div th:replace="${products.productTypes gt 8 and products.productTypes lt 12} ? ~{fragments/products/sub-traditional-products} : ~{fragments/products/sub-traditional-products}"/>
```